# In mapping arrays I am getting, "undefined method `map!'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dictionary

I am attempting to learn how to map arrays. I can't seem to translate [this](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#M000427) into what I need. The first array @fbc has a field "user_id" which refers to "id" in the User model. I don't need to keep the original array so I am using "map!" instead of "map". Instead of creating an array of all users and then mapping, I'm going directly to the database.

In FbComments model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

In User model:

```
has_many :fb_comments
```

This is my best attempt at getting this to work:

```
@fbc = FbComments.where(:reviewee_id => current_user.id)
@fb_comments = User.map! { |u| [u, @fbc.find_by_id(u.user_id)] }
```

The error this produces:

```
undefined method `map!' for #<Class:0x000001049a1078>
```

Not sure of my syntax in the view:

```
<% @fb_comments.each do |fb| %>
   <%= fb[1].name %>: <%= fb[0].comment %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish?

Comment: @ErwinM. 1. Learn 2. Find the most efficient way of matching comment records to user records that contain user names that need to be displayed in addition to their comments.

Comment: @DougR, you helped me on a problem like this before. Any help is appreciated. Tks.

Comment: Thanks, @DougR. I am getting the error msg, "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass". Any insights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `map!` on an array. `User` is a class, not an array, and (assuming it is an AR::Base subclass) it has no 'map!' method defined on it.

Call `User.all.map! {...}`, assuming this is what you are trying to do.

```
@fb_comments = User.all.map! { |u| [u, @fbc.find_by_id(u.user_id)] }
                    ^
```

Comment: Thanks, @DougR. I am getting the error msg, "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass". Any insights?

Comment: Hey, @DougR. Used p @fb_comments and noted that i am getting all users where i think i should be getting only those users for which there is a comment. So i am going to reverse the mapping process.

Comment: Thanks, @DougR. Instead of going straight to the database, I populated two arrays and then mapped it. Couldn't figure out how to reverse the arrays and then put the condition on comments to get only those for which the reviewee_id matches the current_user.id. Your answer lead me there. Thanks.